# Gitlab-CI Deployment stage and task fails with wrong Rancher API Url and Key

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, rancher

I have a Gitlab CI/CD setup that deploys a spring boot application to a DigitalOcean droplet using Rancher.

The task fails with a wrong Rancher API Url and Key error message when in fact, those API details are correct judging from the fact that I have run the deployment manually using the "rancher up" command from the rancher cli.

> Screenshots
>   [image]
>   [image]

.gitlab-ci.yml source

```
    image: docker:latest
        services:
          - docker:dind

        variables:
          DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
          SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

        stages:
          - build
          - package
          - deploy

        maven-build:
          image: maven:3-jdk-8
          stage: build
          script: "mvn package -B"
          artifacts:
            paths:
              - target/*.jar

        docker-build:
          stage: package
          script:
          - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
          - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer .
          - docker push registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer

digitalocean-deploy:
  image: cdrx/rancher-gitlab-deploy
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - upgrade --no-ssl-verify --environment Default
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer:latest
    ports:
    - 8082:8080/tcp
  mta-hosting-optimizer-lb:
    image: rancher/lb-service-haproxy:v0.9.1
    ports:
    - 80:80/tcp
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.agent.role: environmentAdmin,agent
      io.rancher.container.agent_service.drain_provider: 'true'
      io.rancher.container.create_agent: 'true'
  web2:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/username/mta-hosting-optimizer:latest
    ports:
    - 8082:8080/tcp
```

rancher-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
  mta-hosting-optimizer-lb:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
    lb_config:
      certs: []
      port_rules:
      - path: ''
        priority: 1
        protocol: http
        service: web
        source_port: 80
        target_port: 8080
      - priority: 2
        protocol: http
        service: web2
        source_port: 80
        target_port: 8080
    health_check:
      response_timeout: 2000
      healthy_threshold: 2
      port: 42
      unhealthy_threshold: 3
      initializing_timeout: 60000
      interval: 2000
      reinitializing_timeout: 60000
  web2:
    scale: 1
    start_on_create: true
```

Comment: And how does the actual script you run with `upgrade` look?

Comment: @JakubKania, thank you very much for your response. I have modified the issue after realising that I missed something very important out. I have also provided the docker-compose.yml and the rancher-compose.yml files describing the build, packaging and deployment tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the cause of the problem by doing a bit more research online. I discovered that the RANCHER_URL that was required was the base url rather than the full url provided in the Rancher UI. For example, I was initially using the full url generated by the Rancher UI system that looked like this http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/v2-beta/projects/1a5.
The correct URL is http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/.

I set the RANCHER_URL as a secret environment variable in Gitlab Saas (Cloud/Online).

I appreciate everyone that tried to help.

Thank you very much.